# Mule how to make jms outbound endpoint to use ObjectMessage instead of StreamMessage

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule flow, with a custom interceptor, which constructs an Object and forwards it to a JMS outboud endpoint.  The JMS endpoint throws an exception trying to convert the Object to a JMS StreamMessage.   What I want is for the endpoint to convert the Object to a JMS ObjectMessage, instead. How would that be done?

here's my flow;

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="connectionFactoryFactory" name="connectionFactoryFactory"
        class="ConnectionFactoryFactory">
        <spring:property name="properties">
            <spring:props>
                <spring:prop key="imqAddressList">mqtcp://localhost:30001/jms</spring:prop>
                <spring:prop key="imqReconnectAttempts">-1</spring:prop>
            </spring:props>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean id="connectionFactory" name="connectionFactory"
        factory-bean="connectionFactoryFactory" factory-method="createConnectionFactory" />
</spring:beans>

<jms:connector name="JMSConnector" connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
    specification="1.1" doc:name="JMS" />

<flow name="Request" doc:name="Request">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000"
        doc:name="InfoRequest" jobName="InfoRequest" repeatInterval="5000">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <custom-interceptor class="StateRequest"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="JMSConnector"
        doc:name="JMS" topic="requests"/>
</flow>
```

I have also tried adding an Object to JMS Message Transformer;

```
<jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer returnClass="javax.jms.ObjectMessage" name="Object_to_JmsMessage" doc:name="Object to JmsMessage"/>

    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="JMSConnector"
        doc:name="JMS" topic="requests" transformer-refs="Object_to_JmsMessage"/>
```

Comment: Why using an interceptor? Do you want to potentially stop the flow from keeping its execution?

Comment: Also what is the type returned by the interceptor? Does it implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes, there are times when I don't need to request the additional information.  The interceptor creates an object of Request implements Serializable.  I have serialized the object and sent the bytes, which I presume created a BytesMessage, but the server implementer tells me his code will accept only an ObjectMessage.

Comment: The server implementer sucks :) `ObjectMessage`s rely on Java Serialization and thus are tightly coupling, something you do not want in a messaging environment. According to the source code, if the Mule Message payload is a `Serializable` (and not a `List` nor a `String`), Mule will automatically create an `ObjectMessage` without the need to configure any transformer manually...

Comment: I double checked the class; public class Request extends LinkedList<RequestId> implements Serializable{...}. Also public class RequestId implements Serializable{...}. Would the LinkedList bit interfere?  Your previous comment leads me to think it might.

Comment: Totally! Look no further: this class is a `List` so Mule serializes it as a `StreamMessage`. Unfortunately this behavior is in a static class so it's hard to swap with another one. Either create your own JMS ObjectMessage from code or subclass `AbstractJmsTransformer` to create your own flavor of `ObjectToJMSMessage` that would call `JmsMessageUtils.serializableToMessage` for payloads of type `Request`.

Comment: Want to post that last comment in the form of the answer, so I can give you credit?

Comment: Oh sure thanks. Unfortunately I don't have a working solution, just pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Request extends LinkedList<RequestId> implements Serializable`, Mule will automatically convert this type to a `StreamMessage`.

Unfortunately this behavior is in a static class so it's hard to swap with another one. Either create your own JMS `ObjectMessage` from code or subclass `AbstractJmsTransformer` to create your own flavor of `ObjectToJMSMessage` that would call `JmsMessageUtils.serializableToMessage` for payloads of type `Request`.